# App Test not working on iPhone

Tags: iphone, testing, xcode4, ios5

I created an app and when i test it in the simulator it looks perfectly fine and works fine. When i try and test it on my iPhone it doesn't have some buttons and certain things aren't there.  It seems to not have the newer stuff I've added to the app and is only loading the unfinished version.

I want to submit it but it wont load the finished version on my iPhone.

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Seriously? Are you saying that you don't test on a device constantly? That's just asking for a world of pain.

Comment: no i have but i just recently added some buttons and added the retina images and they wont load on the iphone but tehy work perfectly on the simulator. Ive tested it before and it worked on the iphone but now its not after adding some things

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using iPhone 4.0 or later and forgot to set retina images for it...

Comment: no i have the @2x for the images and its an iPhone 4s with 5.0.1 on it. i am new to programming but not that new haha

Comment: @Neel, it it not mandatory to specify retina images for your app. If an "@2x" version is not found, the app scales up the normal image.

Comment: @Sid, I have one project and in that i fetching same issues of layout changing in iOS 5.0, so i have put if else loop according to device and it's work fine..... just set layout according to iOS 5.0...

Answer (score 0):

The problem has two possible causes:

1. Your image names might have been mis-spelled, case wise. If your image is named "IMAGE.png" and in the code, you load it as "image.png", it will show up on the simulator, but not on the device.
2. Sometimes, after adding new images and other resources, try cleaning your project and then build and run, if you can't see the new images.

Also, on the physical device, if all else fails, delete the app and then try rebuilding again.

Are you using the same bundle identifier to build multiple apps to your device? That might be an issue as well. Delete all those apps.

Comment: not only are the images a problem but none of the new buttons i added even show up. They dont even exist on iPhone but in the simulator they are there and working. Why wouldnt the buttons show?

Comment: Did you try the clean and build and also, did you try deleting the app before building?

Comment: This is the only app i have built so far also but i have tested it on 2 different devices. Would that be an issue?

Comment: Then sounds like you need to clean. I can't think of any other reason why it would show up on the simulator, but not on the device.

Comment: On XCode4, on the menu at the top select "Product" and then "Clean"

Comment: i cleaned it and it actually made things worse on the iPhone but in the simulator it ran the same and had no issues.  After the clean it removed my loading image and app icon and it crashes on my iPhone now

Comment: Re-enabling shared library breakpoint 1
Re-enabling shared library breakpoint 2
Re-enabling shared library breakpoint 4
Re-enabling shared library breakpoint 5
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/ANavarro/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader (file not found).
warning: No copy of AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
(gdb)

Answer (score 0):

This may be because your iOS version of simulator & device may be different check in same ios in simulator which is in your device

Comment: im running ios 5.0.1 on my phone and 5.0 on the simulator. would that cause the problem?